# Unable to get principal attributes of user in CAS client

Tags: java, spring-boot, cas

I am trying to set up CAS for SSO in one of my application.
I have set up CAS server with CAS 5.x version, which is working fine for me. Now I want to get user's details like email, role, name etc in CAS client to maintain session of user.

Please find application.properties of CAS server below:

```
##
# CAS Server Context Configuration
#
server.context-path=/cas
server.port=8443

logging.level.org.apereo=DEBUG
cas.authn.accept.users=


#database connection credentials

cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].sql=SELECT password FROM user WHERE email=?
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].healthQuery=SELECT 1 FROM DB.user
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].isolateInternalQueries=false
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].url=jdbc:mysql://172.16.25.137:3306/DB
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].failFast=true
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].isolationLevelName=ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].leakThreshold=10
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].propagationBehaviorName=PROPAGATION_REQUIRED
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].user=envision
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].maxAgeDays=180
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].password=envision@123
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].driverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].passwordEncoder.type=BCRYPT
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].passwordEncoder.characterEncoding=UTF-8
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].fieldPassword=password

cas.authn.accept.users=
cas.authn.accept.passwordEncoder.type=BCRYPT
cas.authn.accept.passwordEncoder.characterEncoding=UTF-8
cas.authn.accept.passwordEncoder.encodingAlgorithm=BCryptPasswordEncoder
cas.authn.accept.passwordEncoder.secret=
cas.authn.accept.passwordEncoder.strength=16

server.ssl.key-store=file:/etc/cas/thekeystore
server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-password=changeit
server.max-http-header-size=2097152
server.max-http-post-size=2097152
server.use-forward-headers=true

server.tomcat.basedir=build/tomcat
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%t %a "%r" %s (%D ms)
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log
server.tomcat.max-threads=5
server.tomcat.port-header=X-Forwarded-Port
server.tomcat.protocol-header=X-Forwarded-Proto
server.tomcat.protocol-header-https-value=https
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=X-FORWARDED-FOR
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
server.error.include-stacktrace=ALWAYS

spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true

endpoints.enabled=true
endpoints.sensitive=true
management.context-path=/status
endpoints.restart.enabled=false
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=false




# CAS Log4j Configuration
#
# logging.config=file:/etc/cas/log4j2.xml
server.context-parameters.isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled=true

cas.authn.oauth.refreshToken.timeToKillInSeconds=2592000
cas.authn.oauth.code.timeToKillInSeconds=30
cas.authn.oauth.code.numberOfUses=1
cas.authn.oauth.accessToken.timeToKillInSeconds=7200
cas.authn.oauth.accessToken.maxTimeToLiveInSeconds=28800

# Attributes that you wish to resolve for the principal
cas.authn.attributeRepository.attributes.uid=email
cas.authn.attributeRepository.attributes.displayName=first_name
cas.authn.attributeRepository.attributes.cn=email
```

Please find code below to get details from AttributePrincipal:

```
AttributePrincipal principal = (AttributePrincipal) request.getUserPrincipal();
        if(principal != null){
         Map<String, Object> attributes = principal.getAttributes();
         if(attributes != null){
         for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : attributes.entrySet())
         {
             System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
         }
         }
        }
```

Please suggest if i need to set up any other property in application.properties of server or if i need to implement any interface in my client application to get user's attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set up cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc* properties in application.properties to get user's attributes in jdbc mode.

Comment: For the setup proposed in this ans, you can reference this tutorial for more insight: https://apereo.github.io/2017/02/22/cas51-dbauthn-tutorial/ if you haven't already